# How come the button doesnt work when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to build this website but the button when pressed does not pop up the screen that will ask to fill with name and phone number and was wondering why this is not working. I am a complete noob when it comes to HTML and CSS, still learning most of the ways and needed help any advice and corrections will be greatly appreicated. Also, I am using JSFiddle I do not know if that makes a difference. Thank you in advance.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
  background-color: clear;
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: red;
}

/* this is for the box on the top of page */
.boxbar_top{
  height:20%;
  width: 100%;
  position: static; /*assign on top when stroll */
  right:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

/*accessing the button layout */
.boxbar_top a {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* bottom layout of screen */
.boxbar_bttom{
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  position: static; /* assign on top when stroll */
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

/*accessing the bottom layput */
.box_bar_bttom a{
    float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* tabs layout */
.tabs{
  background-color: inherit;
  float: center;
  border: 15px solid red;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 20px;
    width:200px;
    height: 100%;
    
}

/*style of the tabs inside */
.tabs-button{
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  padding: 22px 16px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}


.box{
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}



/*show the text when hover through tab */
.hiddenText{
    display: none;
}

.hoverDiv:hover + .hiddenText{
    display: block;
    color: green;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
  position: relative;
}

/* the center of first-last-#...etc */
.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  padding-top: 60px;
}

/*model layput when clicked */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*hover on layout */
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- this is the layout of the first page for crete a cake -->
<!-- this is the problem of aligning the iteams on the right spots -->
<!-- problem the buttons are not shown -->



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta name="description" content="order cake">
    <title>Create Cake</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="boxbar_top">
      <a class="active"> </a>
      <form>
        <select name="dropdown">
          <option value="ENGLISH"></option>
          <option value="SPANISH"></option>
        </select>
      </form>
      <p class="boxbar_top; align: right;">
        <h2 style="color: white; align-items: right;">
          Order your cake online
        </h2>
      </p>

    </div>


    <div class="box">
      <div class="tabs">
        <!-- when clicked pop asked for user name and number  -->
                <div class="imgcontainer">
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('info').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal"> </span>

                <button onclick ="container"> ADD ORDER </button>
              </div>
        <div class="modal">
          <div  class="modal">
            <form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php" method="post">
              
<!-- this is the area pops out when the user hits add order -->
              <div class="container">
                <!-- enter the first name -->
                <label for="fname"><b>First Name</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required>

                <!-- enter the last name -->
                <label for="lname"><b>Last Name</b></label>
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>

                <!-- phone number -->
                <label for="phone"><b>Phone Number</b></label>
                <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}" placeholder="Phone Number" required>

                <!-- submit number -->
                <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>


              </div>

              <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1"> 
                <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('info').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>

              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div  style="tabs-button">
          <button onclick="document.getElementById('info').style.display='block'"> CHECK ORDER </button>
        </div>

        <div  style="tabs-button">
              <button onclick=" ">DELETE ORDER </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="boxbar_top">
      <a class="active"> </a>


    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: what do you expect this to do: `<button onclick ="container">`?

Comment: This is all new to me. I thought when you use the command "onclick" it is simliar to a function call kind of thing similar to c++, I am mistaken by that. Then how would you call a div from a onclick command?

example: onclick="div name"  // not sure how it works

Comment: You can put javascript code in the `onclick`.  But "calling a div" makes no sense. If you wanted it to call a function, use the function name `onclick=MyFunction()`

Answer (score 0):

you have not assigned id to your modal, but have done getElementById('id01')

```
<div class="modal" id="id01">
```

and your btn triggering modal should be sthng like this:

```
 <button type="button" id="btn">Add order</button>
```

and your js:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var modal = document.getElementById("id01");

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```